# Nested max-width and min-width divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following layout.
[image]

I am trying to make yellow and red block fluid, while keeping the green and blue block max-width. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mco4p5zm/).

When I try to expand the screen size green block cuts from rest of layout.

When I try to reduce the screen size the yellow block comes downs.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="block1">
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mco4p5zm/1/)**

ADD this in your code:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Try to expand the screen size green block cuts from rest of layout.